# I can't get entry data in python 3.6

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.6

I made small medical calculator program for python learning.

In this program, when i press "Calc" button, it should be displayed in my command line. But it doesn't work.

Moreover, I suspect that the defined function is operated without button click.

What do i have a mistake?

```
#importing modules
from tkinter import * 

#setting up window
top = Tk()
F = Frame(top)
F.master.title("FeNa Calculator")
F.pack()

#Calc. button event handler
def fena_click():
    ur_na = tUNa.get()
    ur_cr = tUCr.get()
    se_na = tSNa.get()
    se_cr = tSCr.get()

    print('Urine Na : ' + ur_na, end=' ')
    print('Urine Cr : ' + ur_cr, end=' ')
    print('Serum Na : ' + se_na, end=' ')
    print('Serum Cr : ' + se_cr, end=' ')

#add widgets
unit1 = Label(F, text="mEq/L")
unit2 = Label(F, text="mEq/L")
unit3 = Label(F, text="mEq/L")
unit4 = Label(F, text="mEq/L")
UNa = Label(F, text="Urine Na")
tUNa = Entry(F)
UCr = Label(F, text="Urine Cr")
tUCr = Entry(F)
SNa = Label(F, text="Serum Na")
tSNa = Entry(F)
SCr = Label(F, text="Serum Cr")
tSCr = Entry(F)
blank1 = Label(F, text="")
v_Result = StringVar()
Result = Label(F, textvariable = v_Result)
v_Result.set("FENa(%) = ")
blank2 = Label(F, text="")
bCalc = Button(F, text="Calc.", command = fena_click())
bQuit = Button(F, text="Quit", command = F.quit)


UNa.grid(row = 0, column = 0, pady = 2)
tUNa.grid(row =0, column = 1, pady = 2)
unit1.grid(row = 0, column = 2, pady = 2)
UCr.grid(row = 1, column = 0, pady = 2)
tUCr.grid(row =1, column = 1, pady = 2)
unit2.grid(row = 1, column = 2, pady = 2)
SNa.grid(row = 2, column = 0, pady = 2)
tSNa.grid(row =2, column = 1, pady = 2)
unit3.grid(row = 2, column = 2, pady = 2)
SCr.grid(row = 3, column = 0, pady = 2)
tSCr.grid(row =3, column = 1, pady = 2)
unit4.grid(row = 3, column = 2, pady = 2)
blank1.grid(row=4, column = 0, columnspan = 3)
Result.grid(row = 5, column = 0, columnspan = 3)
blank2.grid(row=6, column = 0, columnspan = 3)
bCalc.grid(row = 7, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
bQuit.grid(row = 7, column = 1, columnspan = 2)

#loop running
F.mainloop()
```

[Program view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4hSB.png)

Comment: You need to provide the function itself, not the result, in other words without the parenthesis: `bCalc = Button(F, text="Calc.", command = fena_click)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line where you're making the button, you are actually calling the `fena_click` function. You need to pass the function itself, which you can do by omitting the paranthesis:

```
bCalc = Button(F, text="Calc.", command = fena_click) # no () after fena_click
```